# Row Numbers for backgrid

Tags: backgrid

How to assign row numbers to rows of a backgrid without defining this as one of the columns?
I want to assign row numbers starting from 1; with or without text in header

Answer (score 1):

You can do that slightly inefficiently now like so:

```js
var RowNumberCell = Backgrid.StringCell.extend({
  render: function () {
    return this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model) + 1;
  }
});

var columns = [{
  name: "",
  cell: RowNumberCell,
  editable: false,
  sortable: false
},
...
];
```

Comment: Is there a slightly more efficient way of accomplishing this? While it achieves the basic requirement of adding row numbers, it does not adjust when trying to sort by another column. E.g. If I then choose to sort by a Last name column, the models will adjust and sort correctly but the row numbers remain unchanged.

Comment: @skålfyfan if  you want the row number to change according to how you sort the collection. It means you want each model in the collection to have an "number" to be displayed. In this case you need to modify your definition of model, not modify the backgrid.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a slight edit to Y.H Wong's answer, as I kept getting the following error.

> 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

By using the following code, I was able to get the desired behaviour, albeit using the same slightly inefficient method.

```js
// Row Number Cell.
var RowNumberCell = Backgrid.StringCell.extend({
    render: function () {
        const number = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model) + 1;
        this.$el.text(number);
        return this;
    }
});
```